# Converting MySQL database to UTF16

Tags: mysql, set, character, utf-16

I am trying to create this table in a MySQL database

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Scania` (
  `GensetType` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `EngineType` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `Engine60Hz` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Alternator` text CHARACTER SET utf16 COLLATE utf16_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `PriceEur` float NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

However I receive a error message as

```
Error 1115 <42000> : Unknown character set: 'UTF 16'
```

I even tried to Alter the database but I received the same error

```
ALTER DATABASE nordhavn charset='utf16'
```

I tried searching online about other methods to convert the database but failed to find any possible solutions

Comment: And what does `SHOW CHARACTER SET` show?

Comment: Its shows only UTF8 alongwith some other character sets. Any idea about how to upgrade it if its the case Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `utf16` character set is available [since MySQL 5.5 and up](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/charset-unicode.html).
I guess you're using some earlier version.

Comment: Thanks for the link but I cant find a download link there

Comment: How to best upgrade your installation very much depends on your system. But the official downloads are all here: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/